# Locking row of a referenced table postgres

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, locking

I have a table `A` which is referenced by a table `B` that is to say `A`'s schema looks like this:

```
Table A
(
  id int,
  name varchar,
)
```

While Table `B`'s schema is:

```
Table B
(
  id int,
  a_id int,
  val int
)
```

I have a piece of code that creates a record in table `B`. But, in cases of race conditions say, in case of two parallel transactions, I have a condition in that block which fails and as a result two records are created in table `B` instead of one.
The transaction block looks very similar to this (in Rails):

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do

  # a here is an ActiveRecord Object of Model A
  b = B.new(a_id: a.id, val: value)    # value is -ve

  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback unless b.save

  # this method calculates the sum of val's of all associated records b of a.
  # i.e. find all records from B where b.a_id = a.id and find the sum of val
  # column
  sum = calculateSum(a)

  # below condition fails in race conditions
  raise ActiveRecord::Rollback if sum <= 0
end
```

One solution to this would be to keep a centralized hash of locks whose key would be `A`'s `id` and before entering the block (in my application) I keep on waiting for this lock to be released. This solution would definitely work but I was thinking if Postgres already provides any better solution.

**Edit:** There is no such constraint that `A`'s should have only one `B`'s record. A can have many `B`'s. It's just that in the block of code that I mentioned has a check that fails in case of two parallel transactions.

Comment: Do you mean that each record in `A` should be referenced by at most one record in `B`? If that's the case, just declare the referencing column as `UNIQUE`.

Comment: No, I don't mean that. I have made edit to the question.

Comment: please update your questions with samples of such two rows. please use SQL to query it, not schematic curvy brackets format

Comment: @VaoTsun I've edited the answer to include the transactional block as well as with better schema definitions for the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most general solution to concurrency issues like this is to put your whole block within a [`SERIALIZABLE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) transaction. Put simply, this guarantees that your transactions behave as if they had exclusive access to the database. The main downside is that you may trigger a serialisation failure at any point, with from a simple `SELECT`, and you should be prepared to retry the transaction if this happens. There is [an example on the wiki](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/SSI#Intersecting_Data) which appears to be very similar to your case, which should give you a better idea of how these transactions behave in practice.

Other than that, I think you'll need to explicitly lock something. One possibility would be to lock the whole record in `A` via a `SELECT FOR UPDATE` statement, which will block competing processes in your application, as well as anything else trying to insert a referencing row in `B`. The drawback here is that you might block (or be blocked by) some unrelated operation, like an insert in a different referencing table, or an update of `A` itself.

A better approach might be to take out an [advisory lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-admin.html#FUNCTIONS-ADVISORY-LOCKS) on `A.id`. This is basically equivalent to your centralised hash, but these locks have the advantage of being managed by Postgres, and automatically released on commit/rollback. The caveat is that, because you're taking out locks on arbitrary integers, you want to be sure that you don't collide with some other process which happens to be locking that same integer for some unrelated reason.

You can handle this by using the two-argument version of `pg_advisory_xact_lock()`, and using one of the inputs to identify the type of lock. Rather than maintaining a bunch of lock type constants somewhere on the client side, I find that a useful strategy is to wrap the call for each lock type in its own function, and use that function's [`oid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-oid.html) as the type identifier, e.g:

```
CREATE FUNCTION lock_A_for_insert_into_B(a_id int) RETURNS VOID LANGUAGE sql AS $$
  SELECT pg_advisory_xact_lock('lock_A_for_insert_into_B(int)'::regprocedure::int, a_id)
$$
```

Answer (score 0):

If understand your dilemma, try executing inside a BEGIN...COMMIT block.  For most operations, this takes the place of a lock.  If the instructions fail, the db is unchanged. It is particularly useful for operations where multiple tables much change simultaneously.

Comment: A BEGIN...COMMIT block only ensures that your operations are always executed together or not at all.

Answer (score -1):

*You* have a condition that will block?  That's not how database work.  You don't do anything. They do it. Why is your app conditionally doing anything? The database ensures integrity, it'll be fine. *Centralized hash of locks*? I'm not sure what you're doing.. but you're so far down the wrong rabbit hole, it's gunna take [a lot cleverness to get you out](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Wynx1ukwdVA).

You gotta backtrack. Fast.

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE a ( id_a int PRIMARY KEY, name text );
CREATE TEMP TABLE b ( id_b int PRIMARY KEY, id_a int REFERENCES a, val int );

WITH ti AS (
  INSERT INTO a (id_a, name) VALUES (2,'foo')
  RETURNING id_a
)
INSERT INTO b (id_b,id_a,val)
SELECT 1,ti.id_a,42
FROM ti;
```

Result,

```
TABLE a;
 id_a | name 
------+------
    2 | foo
(1 row)

test=# TABLE b;
 id_b | id_a | val 
------+------+-----
    1 |    2 |  42
```